# How to pass info with React Router to the new page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've made a quick CodeSandBox example what I am after. I have a "Our Courses" section on the landing page with the button "Read more". Once the "Read more" button gets clicked, depending on the Course it would render that information. Now I got the button to work but now I am stuck and can't figure out how to pass relevant information to the redirected page. Now let's say I want to get the Course "Title" and "Description" get passed onto to the redirected page. How can I do that?

CodeSandBox link here - [Link here](https://codesandbox.io/s/try-6brbn?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CardInfo component can look-up the course detail from your courses repository.

To perform the look-up you can determine which card was selected by using the react-router [useParams](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/useparams) hook; this allows you to determine which course identifier was passed via the selected route i.e.

```
import React from "react";
import courses from "./courses";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const CardInfo = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const course = courses.find(course => course.id === id);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{course.title}</h1>
      <p>{course.description}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CardInfo;
```

A complete working example of this can be seen [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-pass-info-with-react-router-to-the-new-page-upx1c?file=/src/components/Card/CardInfo.jsx) (its a fork of your CodeSandBox).

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data between Routes by using the object version of the `to` prop of `Link` component, so change your `Link` component to this:

```
//Card.jsx
<Link 
  to={{
    pathname: `/card/${course.title}`,
    state: {
      description: course.description
    }
  }}>
  <button className="btn">Read more</button>
</Link>
```

Then in your `CardInfo.jsx` component you can access this data by `props.location.state.description`

```
import React from "react";

const CardInfo = (props) => {
  console.log(props)
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        How can I pass course title here depending on which button I click
      </h1>
      <p>{props.location.state.description}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CardInfo;
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

In your `CardInfo` component you can access the `id` provided by the route using the `useParams` from your `react-router-dom` library.

I'm using your `<Route path="/card/:id" component={CardInfo} />` for reference.

Implement it like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

const CardInfo = () => {
  const { id } = useParams()

  return <div>Card ID: {id}</div>
}

export default CardInfo
```

Now that you've got the `id` you should be able to use it for whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple approaches to pass this data:

You can pass data through the link state like this:

```
<Link
    to={{
        pathname: `/card/${course.title}`,
        state: { description: course.description }
    }}
>...</Link>
```

And then read it in the CardInfo component like this:

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const CardInfo = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  console.log(location.state) // { description: 'Lorem ipsum...' }
```

---

However, the best way to do this is to pass the course id in the URL and read the rest of the information from the courses.js file:

This is already correct, you accept the course id as URL paramter:

```
<Route path="/card/:id" component={CardInfo} />
```

Pass the course id in the link:

```
 <Link to={`/card/${course.id}`}>
```

Read the id parameter from the URL and get the rest of the course information from the courses file:

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import courses from './courses'

const CardInfo = () => {
  const params = useParams();

  console.log(courses[params.id]);
```